# How to save solve this: saving images with PIL.Image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

The error occured when I want to save images with PIL.Image 
the code is as following:

```
from PIL import Image
generated = np.load('/home/jovyan/GROUP_SHARED/Kimi.Zhang/cutout.npy')
generated = generated[:25, :, :, :]
print('image_size', generated.shape)

j = Image.fromarray(generated)
for i in range(len(generated)):
    j.save('/home/jovyan/GROUP_SHARED/Kimi.Zhang/imagetest_' + str(i) +'.jpg')
```

"generated" contains 25 images and I want to save them one by one to jpg.

The result is:

### image_size (25, 3, 32, 32)

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in fromarray(obj, mode)
   2415             typekey = (1, 1) + shape[2:], arr['typestr']
-> 2416             mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]
   2417         except KeyError:

KeyError: ((1, 1, 32, 32), '<f4')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-00cdf704f05a> in <module>()
      5 
      6 
----> 7 j = Image.fromarray(generated)
      8 for i in range(len(generated)):
      9     j.save('/home/jovyan/GROUP_SHARED/Kimi.Zhang/imagetest_' + str(i) 
+ '.jpg')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in fromarray(obj, mode)
   2417         except KeyError:
   2418             # print(typekey)
-> 2419             raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")
   2420     else:
   2421         rawmode = mode

TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? 
Thanks very much!

addition:

```
  KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in fromarray(obj, mode)
   2415             typekey = (1, 1) + shape[2:], arr['typestr']
-> 2416             mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]
   2417         except KeyError:

KeyError: ((1, 1, 32), '<f4')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-1316bb4844f6> in <module>()
      7 #j = Image.fromarray(generated)
      8 for i in range(len(generated)):
----> 9     j = Image.fromarray(generated[i])
     10     j.save('/home/jovyan/GROUP_SHARED/Kimi.Zhang/imagetest_' + str(i) 
+ '.jpg')
     11 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in fromarray(obj, mode)
   2417         except KeyError:
   2418             # print(typekey)
-> 2419             raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")
   2420     else:
   2421         rawmode = mode

 TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data in `generated` is *valid*.

- Iterate over the first dimension, keeping track of the index
- ensure correct datatype
- create the Image
- save the image

---

```
...
prefix = '\my\path\prefix'
ext = 'jpg'
for suffix, data in enumerate(generated):
    print(data.shape)
    data.dtype = np.uint8
    im = Image.fromarray(data, mode = 'RGB')
    print(f'{prefix}_{suffix}.{ext}')
    im.save(f'{prefix}_{suffix}.{ext}', 'JPEG')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works. All I did was take one of your lines inside the for loop.

```
for i in range(len(generated)):
    j = Image.fromarray(generated[i])
    j.save('/home/jovyan/GROUP_SHARED/Kimi.Zhang/imagetest_' + str(i) +'.jpg')
```

Comment: sure, in addition